# Splitting NASM assembly source code into libraries

Tags: nasm, ld, yasm

I would like to split my nasm code into several files, so that I can work on different pieces of code separately. However, the only way I found is using nasm `%include` macro. For example. `main.asm` file looks somewhat like this,

```
; ---- main.asm ----
%include "./header.asm"

section .text
    global _start
_start:

    call dummy_func

    mov rax, 0x3c
    mov rdx, 0x0
    syscall
```

while `header.asm` only contains

```
section .text
dummy_func:
        ret
```

I have heard about a way to do this during linking. I got very interested in that, but couldn't find anything appropriate. Is it really possible? If so, can it be done with `ld`? What other means are there to include a static library? (probably some more macros. However I'm not sure "macros" is the right word here)

Comment: I have no urgent need in this, I only wish to learn how NASM works. Thank you for spending your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for static libraries - you can declare the function as external. In your case, `main.asm` would look like:

```
; ---- main.asm ----
section .text
    global _start
    extern dummy_func
_start:

    call dummy_func

    mov rax, 0x3c
    mov rdx, 0x0
    syscall
```

Then compile your source files to object files:

```
nasm main.asm -o main.o
nasm header.asm -o header.o
```

Then you can finally use ld to link the 2 object files into a single executable:

```
ld -o [desired executable name] main.o header.o
```

The `extern` keyword basically means the function `dummy_func` is located in a different object file, and that the object file containing `dummy_func` MUST be linked into the executable at the end. This is a much better way of doing things than using `%include`.

Comment: Thank you. But don't I have to declare dummy_func as a global label? It only works this way

Comment: In main.asm you declare it as extern, however in header.asm you declare it as global. In general, anywhere you want to use a function put it as `extern`, and in the source file where it's actually defined put it as `global`.